# Kivy : Apply function variables to Button Text

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

i got some scroll-available screen example.
and i am testing this example to apply to my application.

and when i launch this python file, i can get this screen like below

[image]

[image]

but what i want is like this above.
I want to make as many buttons as `numberoflist`
And put three lines of `TESTTEST.txt` in one button as shown above.

6, 2, 159, 6, 6, 467 each number is list of `Businfo`
so i can access each number as a `businfolist[0]`, `businfolist[1]`, `businfolist[2]` and so on..

so first, i coded like this for the test.

```
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: 1, 0.35
        padding: 0
on_parent:
    for i in range(root.numberoflist): txt = root.businfolist[i]; self.add_widget(Button(text= txt, id=txt))
```

but it didn't work. Here is Traceback

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "t2.py", line 65, in <module>
     presentation = Builder.load_file("t2.kv")
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 368, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 392, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 501, in parse
     objects, remaining_lines = self.parse_level(0, lines)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 605, in parse_level
     level + 1, lines[i:], spaces)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 605, in parse_level
     level + 1, lines[i:], spaces)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 615, in parse_level
     'Invalid property name')
 kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File "/root/Desktop/hi/t2.kv", line 54:
 ...
      52:                padding: 0
      53:       on_parent:
 >>   54:           for i in range(root.lenbil): txt = root.businfolist[i]; self.add_widget(Button(text= txt, id=txt))
      55:
      56:<MyButton@Button>:
 ...
 Invalid property name
```

And I thought of putting variables in `@Button`, so should I use global?
I have no idea. 
Thank you for reading. I look forward to answering.

t2.py

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
__version__ = "1.0"

import kivy
import os
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.clock import Clock
#from kivy.config import Config #windows size fixed
#Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)
from kivy.core.window import Window 
Window.size = (540, 960)
#Window.size = (1080, 1920) 
##########FOR BUS INFORMATION UPDATE#############
from urllib import urlencode, quote_plus
from urllib2 import Request as RQ
from urllib2 import urlopen as UO
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import os
import datetime


def oopath(ndid, uor):
    path = os.path.join(ndid + '.txt')
    return path

##############################################################################################################

class StationTest(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(StationTest, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    oo = oopath('TESTTEST', 0) #path to nodeidlist, ('nodeid', uor) -->> if uor == 0 >> path to ubuntu
    self.rpandgv(oo)

    def rpandgv(self,path): 
    with open(path) as businfo:
        Businfo= [] 
        nolinenum=businfo.readline()
        while nolinenum!='': 
        Businfo.append(nolinenum)
        leftstations = (businfo.readline().rstrip('\n') + ' stations'.rstrip('\n'))
        lefttime = (businfo.readline().rstrip('\n') + ' seconds'.rstrip('\n'))
        nolinenum = businfo.readline().rstrip('\n')
        Businfo.append(leftstations)
        Businfo.append(lefttime)
        self.businfolist = Businfo
        self.lenbil = int(len(Businfo))
        self.numberoflist = int(len(Businfo)/3)


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("t2.kv")

class Test2App(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation


Test2App().run()
```

t2.kv

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition
#:import Label kivy.uix.button.Label

ScreenManagement:
    transition: SlideTransition(direction='left')
    StationTest:

<StationTest>: 
    name: 'StationTest'
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size 
            source: 'image/background.png' #backgroundimage
    header: _header
    ScrollView:
        FloatLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 500
            BoxLayout:
                id: _header
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: 1, 0.10
                pos_hint: {'top': 1.0}
                anchor: _anchor
                canvas:
                    Color:              
                        rgba: 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 1.0
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                Label:
                    text: "STATION > STATION"
                    font_size: 40
                BoxLayout
                    id: _anchor
                    size_hint_y: 0.3
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:              
                            rgba: 0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    Label:
                        text: "TEST1234"

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: 1, 0.35
                padding: 0
                MyButton:
                MyButton:

<MyButton@Button>:
    text: "contents (%s)"%('123')

    background_color: (255, 255, 255,0.8)
```

TESTTEST.txt

```
6
2
159
6
6
467
6-1
12
832
6-1
3
189
8
8
515
35
4
317
112
10
765
112
2
107
780
30
3067
909
13
1665
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some other problems with your code (that you will discover once you get your Buttons displayed) and some indentation errors in your post. But an easy way to add those buttons would be to add a line in your `StationTest.__init__()`:

```
Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.rpandgv, oo))
```

in place of the line:

```
self.rpandgv(oo)
```

The `Clock.schedule_once` insures that the code is run only after the display is updated and the `.ids` dictionary is filled out. And at the end of the `rpandgv()` method, add the code to add your buttons:

```
    for i in range(self.lenbil):
        txt = self.businfolist[i]
        self.ids.buttons.add_widget(Button(text=txt, id=txt))
```

Also, add:

```
id: buttons
```

to the `kv` declaration of the `BoxLayout` where I believe you want to add the buttons (the one with two `MyButton` declarations).